# Would "metaphor use" be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

As in "metaphor-use" versus "metaphor use".

Comment: No. Not unless it's being used as a modifier, as in _metaphor-use statistics_; but even there the hyphen is optional.

Comment: Why would you think that it _should_ be hyphenated? It's not really a set phrase. 'Use of metaphor' is just as likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "metaphor use" (which could be rephrased as "use of metaphor") would not be hyphenated on its own, but it would be hyphenated when used as a **compound modifier**, ie, a joint phrase forming an adjective for a noun.

See this article on [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen-with-compound-modifiers/):

> A compound modifier consists of two words connected by a hyphen, which act together like one adjective. Usually, compound modifier words could be understood as individual modifiers or nouns, so the hyphen is required to clarify the function of the words.

An example of this would be the phrase "metaphor-use frequency".

Note that this rule is often missed by the casual English user.

Comment: I tidied up your link but please feel free to change back if you wish.